# How to refer to the lower classes perameters of a class in a class in python

Tags: python, class

So I have a class

```
class dog:
    def __init__(self,x,y)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
```

where x and y are classes where they have the values a, b, and c

So if i'm making another object in the dog class, say `def print_a` how can i get the a value of x and y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append another dot to get to the other class attributes. This should do it:

```
class dog:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def print_a(self):
        print self.x.a
        print self.y.a
```

You can also print attributes by name using `getattr`:

```
    def print_by_name(self, attr_name):
        print getattr(self.x, attr_name)
        print getattr(self.y, attr_name)

    # e.g. print_by_name(a) would print self.x.a and self.y.a
```